# How to return result of the nested function in javascript arrow function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Can't figure out how to return result of the nested function in arrow function.

How to express this one (works fine):

```
var stopEating = (function() {
    var loadedStomach = false;
    return function() {
        if(!loadedStomach){
            loadedStomach = true;
            console.log('Stop eating');
        }};
})();
```

as an arrow function (doesn't work properly):

```
const stopEating = () => {
    let loadedStomach = false;
    return () => {
        if(!loadedStomach) {
            loadedStomach = true;
            console.log('Its enough eating!');
        }};
};
```

Comment: When you say "array function" do you mean `=>` function? Those are called "arrow functions". "Arrow" is the English word for the pointy things you shoot from a bow, because they look a little bit like `=>`.

Comment: Also the second version does not actually *call* the outer `=>` function as you do in the first sample of code; there's no `()` on the last line.

Comment: As others have commented, you need to _invoke_ your outer function definition so that it runs its body. The term for this is [IIFE - Immediately Invoked Function Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE).

Comment: Yeah. Of course it’s an arrow! :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the function in order to get the results, thus, adding the parentheses at the end.

```
const stopEating = (() => {
    let loadedStomach = false;
    return () => {
        if(!loadedStomach) {
            loadedStomach = true;
            console.log('Its enough eating!');
        }
    };
})();
```

Answer (score -1):

Into the first example, you created [Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE).

It's a JavaScript function that runs as soon as it is defined. That's why you receive internal function, which prints "Stop Eating".

To realize this pattern you just need to wrap arrow function:

```js
const stopEating = (() => {
    let loadedStomach = false;
    return () => {
        if(!loadedStomach) {
            loadedStomach = true;
            console.log('Its enough eating!');
        }
    };
})();
```